# Is there any way to start the Ruby debugger on exception?

Tags: ruby, debugging, exception

Is there any way to start the/a Ruby debugger whenever the code throws an exception, without me wrapping the code like this:

```
begin
  #do something
rescue
  debugger
end
```

I'd like to have it in such a way that if the `do something` part raises an exception, the debugger will start. It would be nice not having to modify the code to add begin rescue blocks all over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled across this page:[post-mortem debugging](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html#SEC70). Doing this:

```
Debugger.start(:post_mortem => true)
```

gets me where I want to.

Comment: this seemed to work for me previously, but recently no joy with gem 'debugger' :-(

Comment: @SamJoseph did you find a way to do this with the `debugger` fork of the `ruby-debug` gem?

Answer (score 6):

[Hammertime!](http://www.rubyinside.com/hammertime-ruby-interactive-error-console-2942.html)

Comment: Hammertime (modeled after the Squeak exception behaviour) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah, but hammertime doesn't start if native code throws an exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'ruby-debug'
class Exception
  alias original_initalize initialize
  def initialize(*args)
    original_initalize(*args)
    debugger
  end
end
```

This will run the original exception as well as call debugger

Answer (score 2):

if you're using ruby-debug (and it looks like you are), you can set catchPoints for the exception you want.

```
 (rdbg) catch Exception
```

for example

Answer (score 2):

In RubyMine 2.0.x go to Run -> View Breakpoints and click "Ruby Exception Breakpoints" tab, then add the type of the exception you are interested in...

There should be something similar in NetBeans and other Ruby IDEs i guess.

BTW, RubyMine is the BEST!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using gem `debug`, and if using VScode extension "VSCode rdbg Ruby Debugger", and setting env variable `RUBY_DEBUG_POSTMORTEM` to true.