# How to stop with debugger on NoMethodError in NetBeans when running Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, netbeans

- Netbeans 6.9
- JRuby 1.5.0

  - rails 2.3.4

Error example:

```
NoMethodError in Report#week

Showing app/views/report/_list_record.html.erb where line #26 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.sorting

....
```

I can set up breakpoints, the debugger works fine. But when I have a NoSuchMethod error my browser receives a nice HTML page (see above) which informs me about the problem.

It is not enough for me. I want the NetBeans IDE / Debugger to stop where the error occurred. I want an interactive call-stack with variables on every level as if I would place a breakpoint at the right time at the right place.

(Every other development environment knows that and does that by default. I wonder why this one does not...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look here:
[Is there any way to start the Ruby debugger on exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327096/is-there-any-way-to-start-the-ruby-debugger-on-exception)

Comment: Good direction I think. I tried some of those but they lead me to newer errors. I will report back if I have some real thing.